# How do I view the time a flag was handled?

Tags: support, flag-history

Is there a way to view when a moderator handled a flag?

I know I can see the time of flagging (next to my name), and the time the post was made (next to the OP's name with either "asked" or "answered"), but it would be very helpful to also be able to see when my flag was dealt with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a very easy way to do this!

Just hover over the status (helpful, disputed, or declined) and a tooltip showing the time of handling will appear.

Here's an example:

[image: image of tooltip]

Comment: Like 80% of the things on this site have a tooltip that shows a timestamp. Good thing to watch out for in the future.

Comment: @CodyGray Most appear on things that are already clickable though, so you often see them by chance. This (and relative timestamps) seem to be exceptions.

Comment: @River There are *lots* of tooltips on things that aren't clickable.

Comment: @Servy Hmm maybe that just means there's lots of tooltips I haven't discovered yet :)

Comment: No tooltip on my phone. :-(